# Has anyone built an integration with any SMS Receivers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sms, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I want to be able to send a text message to some number and then (upon receiving the text) basically just send a post request off to a different service after receiving the text. Does anyone know of a service I could use to set this up? Would like for it to be as fast as possible

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking how to send a POST request when _sending_ the text, or when _receiving_ a text? Feel free to edit your question to clarify what you are seeking.

Comment: my bad! send a post request off after receiving the message, just edited to clarify

Comment: Currently reading through [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html) which seems along the lines of what i'm looking for maybe

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. Who/what is "receiving the text"? For example, if the message is sent to somebody's cell phone, are you wanting the cell phone to send a POST request?

Comment: Sorry no, I'm imagining the receiver to be some cloud service. So basically, it would be a cell phone would send a text message to a specified number and when that number receives a text message a corresponding post request to a different service would be sent off

Comment: Right now I'm thinking of something like aws pinpoint/sns set up that will receive a text message and then shoot off a request to some lambda service. I'm just not fully sure of how to get that pinpoint/sns to lambda connection configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a summary of the steps to setup a sample app:

1. Navigate to `Amazon SNS` Service → `Topics`
2. Enter `Name` and create a new Topic
3. For the newly created topic, create a subscription where the Protocol is `AWS Lambda` *(see image1 below)*
4. Navigate to `Amazon Pinpoint` Service, create new Pinpoint application
5. Enable `SMS & voice` feature for this Pinpoint application
6. Get a new Long Code *(long code price is $1/month)*
7. For the long code, `Enable two-way SMS`, select the `Choose an existing SNS topic` option and select the SNS topic created in Step 2 above *(see image2 below)*
8. Finally, now you can send a message to that phone number from your phone and it will trigger your lambda function. In your lambda function, you can send a POST request to a different service or do whatever else. You can also respond back to the user's message - see example below.

---

Here's an example of how to send a message using Amazon Pinpoint in Java:

```java
public void sendSMS(String pinpointPhoneNumber, String userPhoneNumber, String messageContent) {
    // define who the message is going to and via what platform
    Map<String, AddressConfiguration> addressMap = new HashMap<>();
    addressMap.put(userPhoneNumber, new AddressConfiguration().withChannelType(ChannelType.SMS));

    SMSMessage smsMessage = new SMSMessage();
    smsMessage.setOriginationNumber(pinpointPhoneNumber);
    smsMessage.setMessageType(MessageType.TRANSACTIONAL);
    smsMessage.setBody(messageContent);

    // add sms message to the direct message config
    // this can have many other types of messages
    DirectMessageConfiguration directMessageConfiguration = new DirectMessageConfiguration()
        .withSMSMessage(smsMessage);

    // put the phone numbers and all messages in here
    MessageRequest messageRequest = new MessageRequest()
        .withAddresses(addressMap)
        .withMessageConfiguration(directMessageConfiguration);

    // create send request
    SendMessagesRequest sendMessagesRequest = new SendMessagesRequest()
        .withApplicationId("put-pinpoint-app-id-here")
        .withMessageRequest(messageRequest);

    // send the message
    AmazonPinpoint pinpointClient = AmazonPinpointClientBuilder.standard().build();
    SendMessagesResult sendMessagesResult = pinpointClient.sendMessages(sendMessagesRequest);
    MessageResponse messageResponse = sendMessagesResult.getMessageResponse();
}
```

---

[image: Creating SNS Topic Subscription to Lambda Function]
[image: Two-way SMS config for Amazon Pinpoint]

Comment: I ended up using twilio following [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python-amazon-lambda), but this is a nice and thorough response. Thanks!